# Question about rolling forecast horizon

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, moving-window

I'm trying to understand how the rolling forecast example below from [Rob Hyndman's blog](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/rolling-forecasts/) works. In the final line of the `for` loop, is `fc` forecasting horizons into the future beyond the end of test?  Or is `fc` meant to be a forecasted version of test, that could be compared to check for accuracy?

My own goal is to create something similar that would train a model and forecast it several horizons in to the future.

Code:

```
library("fpp")
library("forecast")

##Multi-step forecasts without re-estimation

h <- 5
train <- window(hsales,end=1989.99)
test <- window(hsales,start=1990)
n <- length(test) - h + 1
fit <- auto.arima(train)
fc <- ts(numeric(n), start=1990+(h-1)/12, freq=12)
for(i in 1:n)
{  
  x <- window(hsales, end=1989.99 + (i-1)/12)
  refit <- Arima(x, model=fit)
  fc[i] <- forecast(refit, h=h)$mean[h]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `n <- length(test) - h +1`. So the in the last iteration of the loop, the last `h` values of `test` will be forecasted.

The rolling forecast means that you simply refit the model with new observations, i.e. you increase your sample size in each iteration. There is also a variant of rolling fixed-window forecasting where the window length is fixed; you drop the same number of observations from the beginning of the sample as the number of observations you are adding to the end of the sample.